# mouse over array image size should change

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I have implement Java script Games. My game is table formatted. In that array of images stored. when move over on the images image size should be change. ie big image to small image. 
i added the code following please suggest me the suitable answer.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
            document.open("text/plain");
            document.writeln("<table border=3 cellpadding=0 bordercolor=silver width=100% height=450px cellspacing=1 style=\"background-color:#e7e7e7; z-index:5; \" class=\"col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12\">");
            for (j=0; j<Size; j++)
            { document.writeln("<tr width=50px height=0px align=center >");
              for (i=0; i<Size; i++)

              document.writeln("<td class=\"candy\"><IMG src=\"images\ball0.gif\" class=\"img-responsive\" border=0 onMouseDown=\"Clicked("+i+","+j+")\"></td>");
              document.writeln("</tr>");
            }
            document.writeln("</table>");
            document.close();
            </script>
```

Comment: Didya mean the image has to be zoomed in when mouse hovers over it? (Like its being selected?)

Comment: yes correct but. zoom size to be small

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/RC7kb/

```
$('#image').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({width:"100%",height:"100%"});
},function(){
    $(this).css({width:"50%",height:"50%"});   
});
```

Or using plain css:
Whichever image you want to have the hover effect,give it a class :"img-zoom"

```
 .img-zoom:hover {
        zoom: 0.5;
    }
```

You can adjust the image zooming(Width and height) on the .hover function.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS style to your HTML:

```
.img-responsive:hover {
    zoom: 50;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/JguV3/1

Comment: Your image wasn't loading for me.  I set it up with a different placeholder - http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/JguV3/1/

Answer (score 0):

In a table like the one you have there you might be better off shrinking the image (`img`) when you hover over the table cell (`td`).

```
td:hover img { zoom: 0.5; }
```

When you resize or move an image when hovering over itself there is a bit of a browser issue when you hover on an edge that disappears on hover resulting in a flickering off the image.

See the jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/C24w2/1/